# SQL convert DateTime to Date (SQL server 2005)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to convert this:
2014-07-15 15:01:16.880

To: 
2014-07-15

Or to: 2014-07-15 00:00:00:000

What is the best way to do this?

By the way, My database is inside a Microsoft SQL 2005 Server

Thanks in advance

Comment: Date is not a valid type in SQL server 2005 (Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Type date is not a defined system type.)

Comment: Or use `select substring('2014-07-15 15:01:16.880', 1, 10)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Date` datatype in SQL Server 2005, it was added in SQL Server 2008.

To go with your second alternative, you can truncate the datetime to midnight on the same day:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, YourDateColumn), 0)
FROM   YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`CONVERT` to do the conversion.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT('2014-07-15 15:01:16.880', GETDATE(), 112)
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. The question is how to get the date only, without the time